# How can I put content to the right of my bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, nav

So I just recently started using bootstrap, and I created navigation buttons. But for some reason I can't put any content to the right of the buttons. I would like to have a section for content to the right of the buttons with a black background.

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C213D;
}

ul li{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    color: lightsteelblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.nav{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>  
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
            </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the class navbar-right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a continuation to the above question. If you want to make any bottstrap design responsive i.e if you want it to look same in all screen size you should use these classes `col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4` together. Also I have used `col-lg-offset-1` offset classes as it will create a automatic margin(margin of 1 column in this case) between your elements and the design will look good.

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C213D;
}

ul li{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    color: lightsteelblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.nav{
    width: 200px;
}

.main{
     margin-top:50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>  
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-lg-offset-1  col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 main">
             Main content goes here
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use col-* classes of bootstrap, assign certain columns width to your nav and certain column width to your main content.

Check the result in expanded window.

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C213D;
}

ul li{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    color: lightsteelblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.nav{
    width: 200px;
}

.main{
     margin-top:50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>  
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 main">
             Main content goes here
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked but whenever i resize the window the text goes straight to the bottom left of the page.

Comment: Well that's correct behaviour actually. Use col-xs-4 and col-xs-8 instead of col-md-4 and col-md-8